# android java read/write textview from different threads simultaneously

Tags: java, android, multithreading, textview

I have a **TextView** which is being regularly updated from a background thread.

When I try to read it with `myView.getText()` from inside the UI thread it is a matter of chance to get its content between two updates. Otherwise I just get **null**.

Is it possible to use something like synchronized or volatile  on a TextView (or any UI element) to make sure than it cannot be accessed from two threads at the same time ?

EDIT (Solution): Following the direction from @ridsatrio I created the following class:

```
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SyncTextView {
    TextView syncView;

    SyncTextView(TextView view) {
            this.syncView = view;
    }

    private synchronized TextView getSyncView () {
            return syncView;
    }

    public CharSequence getText () {
        return getSyncView.getText();
    }

    public void setText (CharSequence text) {
        getSyncView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the way you went with that decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top of my head, you can perhaps define a `synchronized` method to access your desired `View`. Something along the lines of:

```
public void synchronized TextView getTextViewSynchronizedly() {
    // ..return your view here.
}
```

Once you got this defined, be sure to only allow other components to access your `TextView` through this method.

Answer (score 0):

Please update textview on UI thread only by using post or postOnUiThread. By this way your code will automatically synchronized between read/write call.

Comment: I mean no need to use synchronized here. As it suggested to update view on UI thread only, rest will handled for you by Android itself.